# How do I estimate branch length of a maximum parsimony phylogeny in R?

Tags: r, phylogenetics, phylogeny

I am trying to estimate a phylogenetic tree in R with [ape](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ape) and [phangorn](https://cran.r-project.org/package=phangorn). With `pratchet()` and `optim.parsimony()`, I can estimate a phylogenetic tree, but branch lengths are not estimated. Is there a way to estimate a phylogeny with branch lengths with the following made-up data:

```
x <- data.frame("L1" = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1), "L2" = c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1),"L3" = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1), "L4"=c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1))
```

Comment: Don’t quote your identifiers! It’s `L1`, `L2`, etc.; not `"L1"`, `"L2"` …. R unfortunately allows is but this is a language flaw that should not be exploited.

Comment: Can you provide a link to further information @konrad-rudolph

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh Unfortunately I’m not sure what further information you’re looking for, I’m afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nathan S. Watson-Haigh's answer does give branch lengths, but NOT parsimony branch lengths, which may be what the OP wanted.  `nnls.phylo` is giving distances calculated from a pairwise distance matrix. To get the parsimony branch lengths (i.e. number of changes mapped on to each branch), score the tree against the dataset using `acctran`:

```
treeRatchet <- pratchet(primates)
treeRatchet.BL <- acctran(treeRatchet,primates)
plot(treeRatchet.BL,main='Phylogeny (Parsimony branch lengths)')
```

[image: phylogram with parsimony branch lengths]
Note that the branch lengths in the parsimony phylogram are 'chunkier' than those in the nnls.phylo phylogram -- that's because

1. they are all integers, and
2. they aren't corrected with reference to a model of substitution that considers multiple hits or base composition.

Answer (score 1):

## Terminology

First, a couple of corrections to your use of terminology. A tree *must* have branch lengths associated with it to be called a **phylogenetic tree** as it represents both the relationships between OTU/taxa/leaves *AND* the distances between them (i.e. the branch lengths. A tree where branch lengths have no meaning is called a **cladograms** or a **dendrogram**. You can tell if a tree is a cladogram since all the OUTs/taxa/leaves end at the same position and internal branch lengths are usually (not always) of equal length. Whereas a phylogeny the OTUs/taxa/leaves will typically look "staggered" *and* internal branches will be of different lengths.

Therefore, If the tree you have estimated, truly doesn't have branch lengths estimated and associated with it, it is actually a cladogram.

## Example Derived from `phangorn` Vignette

```r
library(phangorn)

# Get example data
fdir <- system.file("extdata/trees", package = "phangorn")
primates <- read.phyDat(file.path(fdir, "primates.dna"), format = "phylip")

# Calculate pairwise distances between OTUs using Maximum Likelihood
dm <- dist.ml(primates)

# Use the distances to cluster the OTUs using UPGMA algorithm
# This creates a dendrogram
treeUPGMA <- upgma(dm)
plot(treeUPGMA, main="UPGMA")
dev.off()
```

[image]

```r
# Search for different, similar trees to the initial UPGMA tree
# looking for a tree with the lowest parsimony score
# There are 2 search algorithms implemented:
#   optim.parsimony()
#   pratchet()
# These are still cladograms
treePars <- optim.parsimony(treeUPGMA, primates)
treeRatchet <- pratchet(primates, trace = 0)
plot(treePars, main="optim.parsimony()")
plot(treeRatchet, main="pratchet()")
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]

```r
# Calculate branch lengths using the most parsimonious tree identified by
# the pratchet() searchh algorithm
phylogeny <- nnls.phylo(treeRatchet, dm)
plot(phylogeny, main="Phylogeny")
dev.off()
```

[image]

## Choices, Choices, Choices

As you can see from the above example, there are lots of steps to calculating a phylogenetic tree. At each of these steps there may be multiple algorithms to choose from. You choice will depend on the type of data you are analysing, the size of the data set, your available compute resources and the algorithms implemented and available through the tools you use.

Ultimately, you will have to know a fair bit about these algorithms to make an informed choice.